# Linking session ID to database using MYSQL & PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html, database

What do i need help with? - When i upload a image to the database i want to link the ID of the user into the correct field of my SQL. Unfortunately when I am uploading the image nothing is being entered into the field of ID therefore seems to be that it's not capturing it correctly.

So breaking it down: When a user is logged in he has a unique ID i.e. Administrator's ID is 1. When he is at his user panel, he clicks upload second image: He is then directed to this form.

Once at the form he will enter a description, image, and his ID should be taken from the _SESSION.

If any more information is required i am happy to write more.

Thanks in advance,

So... heres the code:

// FORM //

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="secondPic.php">
  <p>
    <label for="name1">Fav Location Name: </label>
  <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" />
  </p>
  <p>
  <label for="photo1">Fav Location Photo: </label>
 <input type="file" name="photo1"><br> 
  </p>
  <p>
  <label for="id">ID: <? echo $rows['id']; ?> </label>
  <input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

// INPUTTING INTO THE DATABASE //

```
<?php
include "common.php";
$secondid = $_GET['id'];
DBConnect();



$Link = mysql_connect($Host, $User, $Password);

//This is the directory where images will be saved 
 $target = "second/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo1']['name']); 


$favname = $_POST["name1"];
$pic2=($_FILES['photo1']['name']); 
$id = $_POST["$id"];



$Query ="INSERT into $Table_2 values ('0', '$id', '$favname', '$pic2')";

if (mysql_db_query ($DBName, $Query, $Link)){
print ("A record was created <br><a href=index.php> return to index </a>\n");

 // Connects to your Database 
 //mysql_connect("localhost", "jonathon_admin", "hello123") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
 //mysql_select_db("jonathon_admin1") or die(mysql_error()) ; 


 //Writes the photo to the server 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 } 


} else {

print (" - Your Record was not created");   
}

mysql_close($Link);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the table when i enter data into the DB:

```
  **s_id  id  favname         pic2  
   1     0  testing the db  piccy.png**
```

Comment: Have you tried testing any of your code?  You really should try figuring out at least how far the code is getting, where the snag is..etc, then post it instead of posting the whole thing.

Comment: are you using sessions? Store the ID in a session and use it in your post

Comment: I'm betting your problem is that `'0'` at the first field of the `INSERT` query. If that corresponds to the PK any subsequent rows will not be inserted. You should specify a field list without the PK, or supply `NULL` (*not* `'NULL'`) to resolve this.

Comment: Thanks for these comments guys, will take a look now, sorry for the title being incorrect and hopefully this thread can be not -2 as aswell as learning im trying to increase my post count :)

Comment: Where is $Table_2 defined? Nice SQL injection holes as well...

Comment: Table_2 is defined in my connection php file. I am still learning PHP so i totally understand this can have SQL injections to itm but it's a learning process i wont learn otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You have no input name for your hidden field.  It looks like you are using id="id" instead of name="id" in your hidden input tag.

Fix that and it should work.

Comment: have changed it, but it did have name='id' therefore shouldnt have made a difference i dont think, but have changed everything.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that there is something wrong with the first file:

```
<label for="id">ID: <? echo $rows['id']; ?> </label>
<input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">
```

The $rows variable is not defined in that file at all, therefore, there is nothing to display.
You have mentioned, that the id is get from the _session variable, maybe you made a mistake, and this shall fix it:

```
  <label for="id">ID: <? echo $_SESSION['id']; ?> </label>
  <input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<? echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>">
```

And dont forget to write:

```
session_start();
```

at the begining of the file, before the html code.

Comment: Yeah still no luck mate, but i think i did need that rather than $rows must have been a error.